# A process cost more time when using multiprocessing

Tags: python, selenium, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, pool

I have 50 tests need to execute concurrently.

And I found that one of the tests "A" cost 1 minutes to be completed (without multiprocessing).

I also try to select test "A" and other few tests (about 5) to execute with multiprocessing, "A" costs 1 minutes too.

But If I execute all tests with multiprocessing, test "A" would cost almost 30 minutes to be completed.

The test "A" started at early but ended at last. How can I find the root cause?

And how can I know whether the Pool always use all workers or not?

(I want to print currently running processes.)

```
            from multiprocessing import Pool

            results = []
            pool = Pool(processes=10)  # start 10 worker processes
            unfinishedTest = testList

            for i in range(0, len(testList)):
                async_result = pool.apply_async(run_test, kwds={'test':testList[i]})
                results.append([async_result, testList[i]])

            while True:
                for r in results:
                    if r[0].ready() and r[1] in unfinishedTest: #Return whether the call has completed.
                        unfinishedTest.remove(r[1])
                        print(r[1], "finished")
                        print("unfinished " + str(len(unfinishedTest)) + " test:", unfinishedTest)

                if len(unfinishedTest) == 0:
                    print("All tests done.")
                    break
                time.sleep(0.25)

            pool.close()
            pool.join()
```

Comment: Is it only the 1st task that finishes out of expected order? What does `run_test` do?

Comment: @IainShelvington Just the function of selenium test. Only the test "A" (not the first task) has this problem.

Comment: You may have issues with all of your tasks competing for the selenium driver?